# Need to select from multiple tables based upon records in one table

Tags: sql, mysql, normalization

heres the situation. I have a table called as maps coordinates the schema is like below:

```
map_coordinates:
item | item_id | latitude | longitude
```

The idea is that this table contains a list of coordinates of different items, they could be a note, a classifieds post, an event etc. I want to be able to set it up so I have a result set as below:

```
item | name of item | latitude | longitude
```

Consider that all events, classifieds and notes are in separate tables. How could I be able to set this up as I need to show all the coordinates on a google maps along with the name of the element i.e if its a classifieds - the title of the ad, an event the title of it etc without having to make alot of sql queries.

I have the code to show it on the map - I just need to grab the details as such. Or do I have to redo my database design here?

========================

EDIT

Actually I have a number of tables in my database such as notes, classifieds and events etc. The point is that an item in the maps_coordinates table refers to the type of the element i.e if its a note or event and teh item_id is the actual id of that event. I don't want to get stuck with using joins here because that would involve alot of tables. Besides I just need to grab basic information as in just the title to help in populating the map so when I hover over the individual markers I don't have to make an ajax call just to show basic information of the element at the marker.

The other tables have their own definitions but all of them have a similar title field and it is this title field I wish to show in the same tuple as the coordinates. Or should I denormalize my tables here and have a duplicate entry for title sin the map_coordinates?

Comment: In the comment to @Georgi's note you mention a NOTES table which contains the name of the note.  Please edit your original post to include descriptions of all other tables involved - otherwise there's not much advice that people can give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a view that combines each of the common elements from the separate tables. In your example note, classifieds post, event, etc.

```
CREATE VIEW viewCommonElements
AS

SELECT 
100      as DataType,
NoteId   as ElementId,
NoteName as ElementName
FROM Notes

UNION

SELECT 
200                as DataType,
Classified_Post_Id as ElementId,
Post_Description   as ElementName
FROM Classified_Posts

UNION

SELECT 
300                as DataType,
EventId            as ElementId,
EventName          as ElementName
FROM Events
```

Simply add a new DataType for each table you have that you want included in your common elements. You can now set up one query that joins to the viewCommonElements view.
If a new element is created later on just modify the view and add a **union select block** giving it a **unique datatype**. You can use the DataType to distinguish the different common elements from each other.
I've used this method several times to harmonize dis-similar but common data.

Comment: +1 As a rule of thumb, I would go for a normalized database set up but keep these kinds of requirements in a view. You don't want to complicate your writes into the database by having too many tables.

Cape Cod's answer above is a good starting point for a view.

Comment: @raja - More times than not, we get stuck with an existing database design that's working (not great but working). Then new requirements come along and ask us to perform miracles on a database that wasn't really designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically your DB design is not good. Try it like this:

```
map_coordinates:
item | item_id | item_type | item_name | latitude | longitude
```

and use a lookup table for item_types.

Comment: Actually Item is Item Types for example: A note has an entery as item: note, itemID: ID of the note.. but I need a way to get the title of the note from the notes table in teh same tuple as the notes coordinates...

Answer (score 0):

You say "The idea is that this table contains a list of coordinates of different items, they could be a note, a classifieds post, an event etc.".  Does this mean that there are different tables for different items? If so, a denormalized table with all the lookup information is likely your best bet. If not, it's just a matter of JOINing the two tables.

Comment: As a follow up, denormalization is not a bad thing when used properly.  Any project of significant scope will utilize both normalized and denormalized data structures if optimized correctly.

Comment: Yes thats exactly how it is - different tables for different elements - could you show a schema for what kind of denormalised table would be in order here?